# How to generate spherical gradient volume

Tags: mesh, volumetrics, emission

I have an object which represents an atom.
I want to show a spherical gradient where the cloud is intense in the centre. It fades away to the edge.

I tried emission but not getting the desired output.

Comment: Volumetric shader with Gradient texture type Spherical. But any volume  even without texture will looks like dense in center and light on edge since volume absorption.

Answer (score 2):

### Volumetric Emmision

- add Emmision shader plugged into volume socket of material Output
- add Transparent
- add Mix shader - with Emmision up
- add Gradient texture > Spherical as factor

### Volumetric Absorption

Instead of Emmision use Volume Absorption node.

### 3D Illusion

In some cases it's quite efficient to fake it by simple circle object with Spherical Gradient texture assigned to alpha. Circle orientation Tracked to Camera, so moving object is always facing to camera that make in illusion of 3d object.

(In case you don't care about shadows.)